# Why is ActiveRecord truncating this timestamp precision?

Tags: mysql, activerecord

I'm using MySQL. I have an ActiveRecord model that behaves like this:

```
record = MyModel.new(some_attrs)
record.save
record.created_at.utc.iso8601(6) #=> "2019-03-07T21:46:19.255634Z"
record.reload
record.created_at.utc.iso8601(6) #=> "2019-03-07T21:46:19.000000Z"
```

Why is it losing all the sub-second precision when reloaded?

Comment: MySQL supports `2019-03-07 21:46:19.255634` in a [DATETIME(6)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) just fine, it can't handle those `2019-03-07T21:46:19.255634Z` formats.  See [example1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e3QAG642jVyFiFzBeLygFf/0) and [example2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e3QAG642jVyFiFzBeLygFf/1) .. the `ISO8601` with `T` and `Z` in the format will not work on MySQL..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the initial timestamp is created by ActiveRecord since MySQL doesn’t have a `RETURNING` clause to say what value it actually inserted. But after reload, it uses the timestamp with lower precision that MySQL is actually storing.